# unable to download composer for xampp version 7.2.0

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Greeting developers, I want to learn laravel framework for my project. For that i follow some instruction in google to install it . i should have composer to install it. i try to download composer but there have some errors.the error is

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:

C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.
), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.
)) in Unknown on line 0
```

i try to resolve it. i check the php.ini file all looking good only. Is that because of i am using xampp server 7.2.0. I am really need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a mistake on your php.ini somewhere, this route:

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll
```

... doesnt look at all correct. "php_php" ".dll.dll"